# YA or children's novel - translator in space

Tags: story-identification

Looking for a story that I read probably in the late 80s - possibly YA but more likely aimed at children. My recollection is that the style was similar to Nicholas Fisk, but I can't find a match in his works (either that or the parts that I'm remembering are obscure enough not to be mentioned).

The lead character was an orphaned girl, who was training to be a translator - there is mention of her spending education periods learning long lists of vocabulary in various alien languages. There is also a scene where she is working, and doesn't recognise a specific word, so has to ask the other party to describe the function of the device (which I think was fairly mundane - something like a cargo hold heater).

There was some background of her parents having taken her travelling (I presume to other worlds) a lot as a younger child, leading to her missing a lot of core education; she was good at her role, but had gaps in her knowledge and skills which caused some friction with her peers.

She is selected for some programme or specific mission with a group of colleagues who were also training for specific roles (pilot? engineer? medic?). There was some early research involved into their destination, and I believe her one contribution was to request a search for silicon-based life (as something like that had killed her parents, having never been found previously).

I can't recall anything of the plot after this, or any of the character names.

Sound familiar to anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having hunted sporadically for this, I'm pretty sure it was '[The Dancing Meteorite](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/5040616-the-dancing-meteorite)' by Anne Mason.

Not a huge amount I can find on-line, but the description on the [Amazon page for the French version](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/0590705415/ref=x_gr_w_bb_sin?ie=UTF8&tag=x_gr_w_bb_sin_uk-21&linkCode=as2&camp=1634&creative=6738) fits:

> Kira Warden is earthbound (experiences inconvenient emotions!) on a
> space-station full of practical scientists. She is the most talented
> e-comm (translator) in the system, but doesn't fit in with the kids
> her age, since she's spent too much time out of (science) school
> because she's been visiting alien planets to learn their languages &
> customs.

The [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/5040616-the-dancing-meteorite) description also sparked a couple of memories:

> Seeing a dancing meteorite and convincing the authorities of its
> existence finally bring Kira Warden, an E-comm cadet on a space
> station, into contact with all the people she has been avoiding due to
> the shock of her parents untimely death in space.

With a few other brief lines I've found in reviews, pretty sure this is the one.